# Delete all files of certain name in nested directories

Tags: shell, find

I have the following file structure:

```
/opt/Data/1
/opt/Data/2
/opt/Data/3

/opt/Data/1/Collection1/a/travel
/opt/Data/1/Collection2/a/travel
/opt/Data/1/Collection3/a/travel
/opt/Data/1/Collection4/a/travel
...
/opt/Data/1/Collection100/a/travel


/opt/Data/2/Collection1/a/travel
/opt/Data/2/Collection2/a/travel
/opt/Data/2/Collection3/a/travel
/opt/Data/2/Collection4/a/travel
...
/opt/Data/2/Collection100/a/travel


/opt/Data/3/Collection1/a/travel
/opt/Data/3/Collection2/a/travel
/opt/Data/3/Collection3/a/travel
/opt/Data/3/Collection4/a/travel
...
/opt/Data/3/Collection100/a/travel
```

Within the 'travel' directory, I have a number of files that have a date at the start e.g. "2020-03-17-".

I want to remove all of these files ONLY within the travel directories.

How would I do this?

I have tried the following:

```
for i in /opt/Data/*/*/a/travel; do find "$i" -name 2020-03-17* -exec rm {}; done;
```

This gives me an error of `nd: missing argument to -exec` which I cannot seem to solve.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but apparently a loop is not required here. Just select files whose path matches `*/travel/2020-03-17-*` and delete them.

```
find /opt/Data -type f -path '*/travel/2020-03-17-*' -exec echo rm {} +
```

This assumes there is no **directory** in `travel` whose name starts with `2020-03-17-`.

If the output looks good, drop `echo`.